# Inherit from classes passed to constructor as a template parameters an inherit from them

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, variadic-templates

I want to have something like that:

```c++
template<class... Args>
class MyClass : public Args
{
    MyClass<class... Args>(/*some parameters*/)
    { }
}

// ana then:
MyClass<Base1, Base2, Base3>(/*some arguments*/)
```

That i want to `dynamic_cast` to `Base1` or etc. and to use his methods.

I know that this code will not work, but do you have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: You mean `class MyClass : public Args...`?

Comment: @hshsvagen Note that for the constructor you don't have to specify the template arguments

Comment: Maybe what you are after: [template argument deduction in constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). That's new, possible since C++17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine:

```
struct Base1
{};
struct Base2
{};
struct Base3
{};

template<class... Args>
struct MyClass : public Args...
{};

MyClass<Base1, Base2, Base3> mc;
```

There is no need for the `<>` in your constructor, you are missing "..." after `public Args` and you are missing a ";" at the end of your class definition.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that this code will not work, but do you have any ideas how to do it?

To make it works you have to

(1) add the ellipsis (`...`) inheriting `Args...`

```
class MyClass : public Args...
// ........................^^^
```

(2) make `MyClass` a `struct` or make `public` the constructor

(3) remove the `<class... Args>` part defining the constructor (it's implicit)

(4) add some as follows

```
   Args const & ... as
```

for constructor arguments

(5) add a semicolon closing the class or struct

Now the following code works

```
struct Base1 {};
struct Base2 {};
struct Base3 {};

template<class... Args>
struct MyClass : public Args...
 {
   MyClass (Args const & ...)
    { }
 };

int main()
 {
   MyClass<Base1, Base2, Base3>(Base1{}, Base2{}, Base3{});

   MyClass(Base1{}, Base2{}, Base3{});  // C++17 only
 }
```

Observe the last line in `main()`

```
MyClass(Base1{}, Base2{}, Base3{});  // C++17 only
```

Works only from C++17 because uses a new C++17: deduction guides.

In your case, there is an implicit deduction guides that permit to deduce the template types of the class from the types of the argument passed to the constructor.

Another example of use (more useful?) could be

```
MyClass  mc{ Base1{}, Base2{}, Base3{} };
```

Answer (score 1):

At very first, you are using invalid syntax. When using variadic templates, you need to 'unpack' them (correct term: 'expand the parameter pack') when using them:

```
template<typename... Args>
class MyClass : public Args ...
//                          ^^^
{ };
```

In the constructor, you can skip the template parameters entirely, but *if* you specify them, you need to 'unpack' them again:

```
MyClass<Args ...>(/*some parameters*/);
//     ^^^^^^^^^^   optional
```

Once the class is defined, you can specify the template arguments just as with classic templates, solely that the number can differ:

```
MyClass<Base1> c1;
MyClass<Base1, Base2> c2;
MyClass<Base1, Base2, Base3> c3;
```

Since C++17 and with appropriate constructor, you can even let the class template arguments get deduced:

```
template<typename... Args>
class MyClass : public Args ...
{
public:
    MyClass(Args const&... args)
        : Args(args)... // call base class copy constructors!
                        // (note the unpacking again)
    { }
    MyClass(Args&&... args)
        : Args(std::forward(args))... // call base class move constructors!
                                      // (note the unpacking again)
    { }
};

MyClass c0;
MyClass c1(Base1());
MyClass C2(Base1(), Base2());

std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(c0), MyClass<>> << std::endl;
std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(c1), MyClass<Base1>> << std::endl;
std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(c2), MyClass<Base1, Base2>> << std::endl;
```

Note that inheritance is a red herring here, that works without as well. See [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you some working example as you requested:

```
#include<iostream>

class B1 {
private:
int *m;
public:
B1() { m = new int;}
~B1() { delete m;}
void SetM(int a) { *m = a;}
int GetM() { return *m;}
};

class B2 {
private:
std::string str;
public:
B2() { str = "";}
~B2() {}
void SetStr(std::string a) { str = a;}
std::string GetStr() { return str;}
};

class B3 {
private:
float f;
public:
B3() { f = 0.0 ;}
~B3() {}
void SetF(float a) { f = a;}
float GetF() { return f;}
};

template<class... Args>
class MyClass : public Args... {
};

int main () {
MyClass<B1,B2,B3> l;
l.SetM(1);
if (auto a = dynamic_cast<B1*>(&l)) {
    std::cout<<" " << a->GetM() <<"\n";
} else {
    std::cout<<"ERROR:\n";
}

}
```

Hope this helps,
Thanks,

Rajkumar

Comment: And why `new`?.

Comment: Nothing specific, I want to show the usage of dynamic_cast as well, that's all.

Comment: As far as i understand, we need virtual method to use dynamic_cast here